# Convert UTC time to system time getting null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
 NSString *strUTCTime=@"2017-07-06T10:00:00";

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";

 NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
 [dateFormatter setTimeZone:destinationTimeZone];

 NSDate *oldTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strUTCTime];

 NSString *estDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:oldTime];
 NSLog(@"Local time is ===> %@",estDateString);
```

Comment: You need to debug yourself, or at least show us some usefull results. For instance `oldTime` is `nil`, that's why `estDateString` will be nil anyways. So your issue is from getting `oldTime`. In fact, I removed the `timeZone` stuff to check if I could get a `NSDate` and not. It help me find that the issue is with the `dateFormat`, you need to "escape" the `T` => `dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";`

Comment: Yes need to escape the T   Thanks.    =====>                        
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";

Answer (score 1):

Here are the following working and tested code.

```
NSString *strUTCTime=@"2017-07-06T10:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *oldTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strUTCTime];

NSLog(@"UTC time is ===> %@",oldTime);

NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:destinationTimeZone];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

NSString *estDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:oldTime];
NSLog(@"Local time is ===> %@",estDateString);
```

Please let me know if it works.